# jQuery Multiple Slider action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have 3 jQuery sliders on the same page:-

```
jQuery('.slider-deposit').slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 3800,
    max: 30000,
    value: 3848,
    step: 500,
    slide: function(event, ui) {            
        jQuery(".calc-deposit").html('£'+ui.value);
});

jQuery('.slider-loan').slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 15400,
    max: 120000,
    value: 15393,
    step: 2000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(".calc-loan").html('£'+ui.value);
    }
});

jQuery('.slider-mortgage').slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 57000,
    max: 450000,
    value: 57724,
    step: 7500,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(".calc-mortgage").html('£'+ui.value);
    }
});
```

On change on ANY of the sliders I want to update a value on the page, how can this be achieved?

I did try:-

```
jQuery('.slider').slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {            
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can DRY up your code by using `data` attributes on the HTML element you instantiate the slider on. This will then allow you to run the same code on the `slide` event of all three. Try this:

```
<div class="slider" data-min="3800" data-max="30000" data-value="3848" data-step="500" data-target=".calc-deposit"></div>
<div class="slider" data-min="15400" data-max="120000" data-value="15393" data-step="2000" data-target=".calc-loan"></div> 
<div class="slider" data-min="57000" data-max="450000" data-value="57724" data-step="7500" data-target=".calc-mortgage"></div>
```

```js
$('.slider').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.slider({
        range: "max",
        min: $el.data('min'),
        max: $el.data('max'),
        value: $el.data('value'),
        step: $el.data('step'),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $($el.data('target')).html('£' + ui.value);

            // place code here which will execute when *any* slider moves
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mnq3cbuo/)

Answer (score 1):

The [**API**](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) gives an `event`:-

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slide", function( event, ui ) { } );
```

so if all sliders have the class `slider`, then bind that after you initialize them:-

```
jQuery('.slider').on( "slide", function( event, ui ){          
    alert('test');
});
```